# How to deserialize JSON API response with two the same id?

Tags: javascript, typescript, json-deserialization, json-api

I have a response data from php in JSON API format. The data I received I deserialize it using this library [jsona](https://github.com/olosegres/jsona), but after deserializing it the second data gets overwritten with what is in the previous. How do I fix this?

Hint: This is a result of query, a brand from brand_table, and left join to a company_table, so a single brand can be in two different company which my purpose is to display it in the front end like this:

```
| Brand   | Company   |
| Brand A | Company Z |
| Brand A | Company Y |


Query: 
SELECT brands.*, company_brands.company_id, company_brands.status FROM brands LEFT JOIN company_brands ON company_brands.brand_id = brands.id
```

```js
import Jsona from 'jsona';


const jsona = new Jsona();


const data = {
  "meta": {
    "page": {
      "current-page": 1,
      "per-page": 25,
      "from": 1,
      "to": 2,
      "total": 2,
      "last-page": 1
    }
  },
  "data": [{
      "type": "brands",
      "id": "105",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Brand A",
        "status": "pending",
        "company_id": 1
      },
    },
    {
      "type": "brands",
      "id": "105",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Brand A",
        "status": "approved",
        "company_id": 2
      },
    }
  ]
}

const test = jsona.deserialize(data)
console.log('result', test);
```

But the result I get is this:

```
[{
  type: "brands"
  id: "105"
  name: "Brand A"
  status: "pending"
  company_id: 1
},
{
  type: "brands"
  id: "105"
  name: "Brand A"
  status: "pending"
  company_id: 1
}]
```

Comment: Hello can you explain a bit more.

Comment: @ChafikKerboute, hi. on which part? The result I get from the deserialize has the same `company_id` and `status` when it should be different.

Comment: Ah , i understand let me think about this situation for a bit .

Comment: can you provide the query you are using ?

Comment: @ChafikKerboute, sure I updated my question with the mysql query related to it. I'm actually using Laravel Eloquent, but that is basically what the SQL query equivalent. Hope that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your server isn't generating a valid JSON:API response as the `id` should be unique for a particular resource object `type`.

From the JSON:API specification: https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-identification

> Within a given API, each resource object’s type and id pair MUST identify a single, unique resource. (The set of URIs controlled by a server, or multiple servers acting as one, constitute an API.)

Generally you should be modelling two resources, `brand` and `company` and there would be a many-to-many relationship from `brand` to `company`.

The query would then be for `brand` and use the Compound Documents feature to also include data for `company` probably using Sparse Fields to select the specific data fields you require.

`/brand?include=company`